# My ipod 1st gen is disabled for 45 years and wont sync to my laptop since it is disabled

Tags: itunes

I no longer know where my old computer which was synced with my 1st gen is. my ipod 1st gen is now disabled for 45 years and I cannot sync it with me new laptop since it is disabled
WHAT DO I DO!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: [This iPod?](http://apple-history.com/images/models/ipod.jpg)

Comment: Which iPod is it? If it's an iPod touch then you need to put it into recovery mode and connect it into a computer